# DataSourceContextHolder.setTargetDataSource() doesnt work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lazy-initialization

I have a bootstrap.yml file with some DB datasources in my spring boot project. I'm using `DataSourceContextHolder.setTargetDataSource("Datasource")` to change datasource connection to get information from other DB schema but spring doesn't change the datasource and continues using the last who connected with. I tried to use open in view = true but now we have lazyInitException so I'm very blocked and confused. Any idea to solve that?

This is a method Im using to access to the DB info, in one of my classes:

```
public Contract getAccount(String cdisoloc, String accountId) {
        DataSourceContextHolder.setTargetDataSource(cdisoloc);

        Optional<Contract> result = contractJpaRepository.findById(AccountUtils.mapAccountIdToPk(accountId));

        return result.orElseThrow(() ->
                new NotFoundException("Account " + accountId + " not found.", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, ErrorConstants.ERROR_NO_DATA_FOUND));
    }
```

This is one of datasource definitions in the bootstrap.yml:

```
vcap:
  services:
    - name: as400-PIT-ARCHIVE-AT
      credentials:
        type: datasource
        username: XXX
        password: XXXX
        driver-class-name: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
        as400Url: servername.example.com
        jdbcUrl: jdbc:as400://servername.example.com;naming=system;libraries=ICOMBATB
        connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1 FROM CONTRACT FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
        location: ARCAT
        maximumPoolSize: 2
        minimumIdle: 1
        idleTimeout: 120000
        maxLifetime: 120000
      label: user-provided
```

This is the DataSourceContextHolder class:

```
package com.example.fce.bas.database;

public final class DataSourceContextHolder {

    private DataSourceContextHolder() {

    }

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> CONTEXT_HOLDER = new ThreadLocal<String>();

    public static void setTargetDataSource(String targetDataSource) {
        CONTEXT_HOLDER.set(targetDataSource);
    }

    public static String getTargetDataSource() {
        return (String) CONTEXT_HOLDER.get();
    }

    public static void resetDefaultDataSource() {
        CONTEXT_HOLDER.remove();
     }
}
```

This is the ContractJpaRepository class:

```
package com.example.fce.bas.account;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;


@Repository
public interface ContractJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Contract, ContractPK> {

    List<Contract> findTop50ByCdisoloc(String cdisoloc);

}
```

This is the DataSourceRouter class:

```
package com.example.fce.bas.database;

import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource;

public class DataSourceRouter extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return DataSourceContextHolder.getTargetDataSource();
     }
}
```

This is the DataSourceConfiguration class:

```
package com.example.fce.bas.database;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

import java.util.HashMap;

@Data
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSourceServices service(HashMap<String, DataSourceServices.DataSourceObject> cupsServices) {
        return new DataSourceServices(cupsServices);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("vcap.services")
    public HashMap<String, DataSourceServices.DataSourceObject> getCUPS() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```

This is the DataSourceServices class:

```
package com.example.fce.bas.database;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.HashMap;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DataSourceServices {
    private HashMap<String, DataSourceObject> dataSourceServices;

    @Data
    @Component
    public static class DataSourceObject {
        private DataSourceCredentials credentials;
        @SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:membername")
        private String syslog_drain_url;
        @SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:membername")
        private Object volume_mounts;
        private String label;
        private String name;
    }

    @Component
    @Data
    public static class DataSourceCredentials {

        private String type;
        private String as400Url;
        private String jdbcUrl;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private String driverClassName;
        private String connectionTestQuery;
        private String location;
        private int maximumPoolSize;
        private int minimumIdle;
        private long idleTimeout;
        private long maxLifetime;
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the DatabaseConfiguration:

```
package com.example.fce.bas.database;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.ibm.as400.access.AS400;
import com.ibm.as400.access.AS400SecurityException;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    private final DataSourceServices cups;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseConfiguration(DataSourceServices cups) {
        this.cups = cups;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return getDataSources(this.cups);
    }

    @Bean
    public HashMap<String, AS400> as400() {
        return getAs400List(this.cups);
    }

    private DataSource getDataSources(DataSourceServices dataSourceServices) {
        final DataSource[] defaultDatasource = {null};
        DataSourceRouter routingDataSource = null;
        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();

        if (dataSourceServices.getDataSourceServices() != null) {
            routingDataSource = new DataSourceRouter();
            dataSourceServices.getDataSourceServices().keySet().forEach(k -> {

                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
                DataSourceServices.DataSourceObject dataSourceObject = mapper.convertValue(
                        cups.getDataSourceServices().get(k),
                        DataSourceServices.DataSourceObject.class);

                if (dataSourceObject.getLabel().equals("user-provided")
                        && dataSourceObject.getCredentials().getType().equals("datasource")) {
                    String url = dataSourceObject.getCredentials().getJdbcUrl();
                    String user = dataSourceObject.getCredentials().getUsername();
                    String password = dataSourceObject.getCredentials().getPassword();
                    String driverClassName = dataSourceObject.getCredentials().getDriverClassName();
                    String connectionTestQuery = dataSourceObject.getCredentials().getConnectionTestQuery();
                    String location = dataSourceObject.getCredentials().getLocation();
                    int maximumPoolSize = dataSourceObject.getCredentials().getMaximumPoolSize();
                    int minimumIdle = dataSourceObject.getCredentials().getMinimumIdle();
                    long idleTimeout = dataSourceObject.getCredentials().getIdleTimeout();
                    long maxLifetime = dataSourceObject.getCredentials().getMaxLifetime();

                    defaultDatasource[0] = createDataSource(url, user, password, driverClassName, connectionTestQuery,
                            maximumPoolSize, minimumIdle, idleTimeout, maxLifetime);
                    targetDataSources.put(location, createDataSource(url, user, password, driverClassName, connectionTestQuery,
                            maximumPoolSize, minimumIdle, idleTimeout, maxLifetime));
                }
            });
            routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
            routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(defaultDatasource[0]);
        }
        return routingDataSource;
    }

    private HashMap<String, AS400> getAs400List(DataSourceServices dataSourceServices) {
        HashMap<String, AS400> targetAS400 = new HashMap<>();

        if (dataSourceServices.getDataSourceServices() != null) {
            dataSourceServices.getDataSourceServices().keySet().forEach(k -> {

                DataSourceServices.DataSourceObject dataSourceObject = getDataSourceObject(k);

                if (dataSourceObject.getLabel().equals("user-provided") && dataSourceObject.getCredentials().getType().equals("datasource")) {
                    String url = dataSourceObject.getCredentials().getAs400Url();
                    String user = dataSourceObject.getCredentials().getUsername();
                    String password = dataSourceObject.getCredentials().getPassword();
                    String location = dataSourceObject.getCredentials().getLocation();

                    targetAS400.put(location, createAS400(url, user, password));
                }
            });
        }
        return targetAS400;
    }

    private DataSource createDataSource(String dataSourceUrl,
                                        String dataSourceUser,
                                        String dataSourcePassword,
                                        String dataSourceDriverClassName,
                                        String dataSourceConnectionTestQuery,
                                        int maximumPoolSize,
                                        int minimumIdle,
                                        long idleTimeout,
                                        long maxLifetime) {

        String dataSourceUrlOrNull = stringOrNull(dataSourceUrl);
        if (dataSourceUrlOrNull == null) {
            return null;
        }
        HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
        ds.setJdbcUrl(dataSourceUrlOrNull);
        ds.setUsername(stringOrNull(dataSourceUser));
        ds.setPassword(stringOrNull(dataSourcePassword));
        ds.setDriverClassName(stringOrNull(dataSourceDriverClassName));
        ds.setConnectionTestQuery(stringOrNull(dataSourceConnectionTestQuery));
        ds.setMaximumPoolSize(maximumPoolSize);
        ds.setMinimumIdle(minimumIdle);
        ds.setIdleTimeout(idleTimeout);
        ds.setMaxLifetime(maxLifetime);

        return ds;
    }

    private AS400 createAS400(String dataSourceUrl,
                              String dataSourceUser,
                              String dataSourcePassword) {

        AS400 as400 = new AS400(dataSourceUrl, dataSourceUser, dataSourcePassword);

        try {
            as400.validateSignon(dataSourceUser, dataSourcePassword);
            System.out.println("AS400 Sign on validated for " + dataSourceUser + " in " + dataSourceUrl);
        } catch (AS400SecurityException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return as400;
    }

    private DataSourceServices.DataSourceObject getDataSourceObject(String k) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return mapper.convertValue(cups.getDataSourceServices().get(k), DataSourceServices.DataSourceObject.class);
    }

    private String stringOrNull(String value) {
        return StringUtils.isEmpty(value) ? null : value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you obtaining the `DataSource` instance? Show the code that reads from the datasource.

Comment: Ok sorry. This is one of the methods im using to access DB info in my spring boot project and the one of the datasource conection in the bootstrap.yml. I put all in the main thread

Comment: And `contractJpaRepository` class as well

Comment: ok, I put all the info in the main thread again. thanks :)